# Python Panda reading multiple excel file using different date

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, datetime

I have 6 files that I want to read through pandas. I know how to read excel files using the below code.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("1a_2019-10-31_00_00_00.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("2a_2019-10-31_00_00_00.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv("3a_2019-10-31_00_00_00.csv")
```

I want to use this code on month-end basis, so I want to make `2019-10-31` as a variable, so something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv("1a_YYYY-MM-DD_00_00_00.csv")
```

So I define the date in one place and all files names with date are updated with the new month end date.
How do I make it so that I just define the date in one place and `pd.read_csv` get updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Python 3.6 or over, you can use f-strings:

```
date_str = "2019-10-31"

df1 = pd.read_csv(f"1a_{date_str}_00_00_00.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv(f"2a_{date_str}_00_00_00.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv(f"3a_{date_str}_00_00_00.csv")
```

Otherwise, just simply concatenate the strings:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(f"1a_" + date_str + "_00_00_00.csv")
```